# PSYouTubeExtractor Error while Extraction

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

I am trying to use the [PSYouTubeExtractor](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor#readme) in my Project, it is supposed to help with displaying YouTube videos inline by either downloading the mp4 or displaying it in a web view.

Here is how I implemented it so far:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [PSYouTubeExtractor extractorForYouTubeURL:[deskUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] success:^(NSURL *URL) {
        NSLog(@"Finished extracting: %@", URL);
        // show the movie!
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to query mp4: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

`deskUrl` is: [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMsLArefSOw) for example and while this is extracting an error occurs:

```
[PSYouTubeExtractor doRetry_] [Line 105] Trying to load page...
2012-09-30 17:50:40.054 Tube[3378:907] -[__NSCFString absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21027eb0
```

Well, I do not understand why, because this is just how it should be done. On the github page of the developer [here](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor), this is just the same code.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the new version? [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView)

Answer (score 2):

It expects a `NSURL` instance but you obviously are providing an `NSString` instance.

Convert your string into a URL using the following call;

```
NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[deskUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Then you may use the extractor factory/singleton as already done in your example;

```
[PSYouTubeExtractor extractorForYouTubeURL:youTubeURL success:^(NSURL *URL) {
        NSLog(@"Finished extracting: %@", URL);
        // show the movie!
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to query mp4: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I obviously missed that